# Catching RuntimeExceptions on grails transactions

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, quartz-scheduler

Currently, we have a grails job that calls a transactional service. When an exception is thrown from the service, the behavior of hibernate becomes weird. We are using grails 2.4.4 and hibernate:3.6.10.18.

So inside my job I have this on the execute method:

```
Model.withTransaction { ->
    try {
        service.updateDatabase()
        service.method()//throws runtime exception
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            //do something
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, the `updateDatabase` operation does rollback. Looking at the logs, I can verify that it goes through in the catch block but still logs indicate that exception is still thrown. I thought that is why the transaction is rolling back.

But if I throw the `RuntimeException` directly on the job, it does NOT rollback the database transaction and the exception is cleanly caught. Under my impression, this should be the proper behavior, and it should be the same as throwing the exception from inside the service.

```
Model.withTransaction { ->
    try {
        service.updateDatabase()
        throw new RuntimeException()
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            //do something
    }
}
```

Is this normal?
Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, if you help me clear it out I will be able to help you. First you say "_The weird thing is, the updateDatabase operation does not rollback_" and then "_I thought that is why the transcation is rolling back._". Help me understand if updateDatabase ir rolling back or not.

Comment: @juandiegoh Sorry about that typo, I updated the question.

Comment: I answered what I supposed was your problem, but I still don't get it. Your case does NOT rollback and what you think is the "proper behaviour" does  not rollback either.

Comment: @juandiegoh Again apologies, corrections on my question have been applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected behaviour is:

```
Model.withTransaction { -> // Creates new Transaction
    try {
        service.updateDatabase() // uses the same Transaction that was created before
        service.method() // uses the same Transaction that was created before
                         // throws runtime exception
                         // sets Transaction as rollbackOnly
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            //do something
    }
} // as the Transaction was set as rollbackOnly it rollbacks everything that was done before
```

Basically that is the expected behaviour, now the explanation.

All your service methods are Transactional because your service has a @Transactional above its name.

```
@Transactional
class MyTransactionalService {
...
}
```

And by default every Transactional method have the PROPAGATION.REQUIRED property set.

```
/**
* Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
* Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
* <p>This is the default setting of a transaction annotation.
*/
REQUIRED(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED)
```

This means that when the service method runs it uses the current transaction that was created in your Job. Here comes the tricky part, when a functionality has more than one Transactional part it evaluates the rollback condition for every one of them, so when your **method()** throws RuntimeException it sets your transaction as rollbackOnly but continues until that Transaction is over (when your Model.withTransaction.. finishes) and just in that moment it rollbacks everything.

Going deeper, you have three parts where your Transaction can be set to rollbackOnly.

1. if *updateDatabase()* throws an Exception, all the Transaction will be set as rollbackOnly
2. if *method()* throws an Exception, all the Transaction will be set as rollbackOnly
3. if the closure that you pass to *withTransaction{..}* throws an Exception, all the Transaction will be set as rollbackOnly.

The transaction will rollback when the Transaction is over, and that moment is after the *withTransaction{..}* finishes.

So you need to be really careful with your Transactions.

To solve your problem you can make your **method()** not Transactional by setting just the **updateDatabase()** as transactional in your Service class and deleting the @Transactional from above the service name.

```
class YourService {

    @Transactional
    def updateDatabase() {
        //...
    }

    def method() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Setting just one method as @Transactional makes just that method as Transactional instead of having all the methods transactional.

I made a project as an example so you can run the tests and check it for yourself, also I set the log4j to show the life of the Transaction so you can understand it better, you just need to run the MyProcessorIntegrationSpec.groovy

https://github.com/juandiegoh/grails-transactions-rollback

Hope it helps!

Comment: Having a transaction wrapped on both service calls means both service.updateDatabase and service.method will be in the same transaction regardless if I remove the annotation on the service method right? So if I set the method() as non transactional, it will still be transcational. As you said, using the job's transaction.

Comment: Also am I correct to assume that catching the runtime exception means it will no longer be set to rollback only? And that's the reason the 2nd scenario does NOT rollback

Comment: Every time a Transactional method ends with a RuntimeException it sets the transaction as rollbackOnly. If you set YourService as I told you in the answer it means that _updateDatabase()_ is transactional and _method()_ is not, so if method ends with a RuntimeException it will not set the transaction as rollbackOnly.

Comment: The reason the second scenario is not rolling back is because there is no transactional method that is ending throwing an Exception. _updateDatabase()_ is not ending with an Exception and _Model.withTransaction { .... }_ is not ending with an Exception neither.